# get a subset of a dataframe by sampling for each value in a column

Tags: r, memory, split, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` where all the rows have a value `uid` corresponding to a user id, and multiple rows can have the same uid. I want to create a new dataframe that only includes a random sample of `x` rows for each uid.

I wrote this function:

```
trim <- function(df, max){
    data.by.user <- split(df, df$uid) #split the dataframe by user
    output <- NULL
    lapply(data.by.user, function(x){

        #length(x$tid) = number of rows for that user

        if(is.null(output){
            if(length(x$tid) <= max){
                output <<- x
            }
            }else{
                output <<- x[sample(nrow(x), size = max),]
            }
        }else if (length(x$tid) <= max){
            output <<- rbind(output, x)
        }else{
            output <<- rbind(output, x[sample(nrow(x), size=max),]) #sample 'max' rows from x
        }
    })
    return(output)
}
```

But when I try it on my dataframe (which has several million rows),

```
d <- trim(old_df, 200)
```

it runs out of memory and gets this error along with warnings about having reached the total allocation of memory:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 442 Kb
```

Is there a more memory-efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd avoid working with (subsets of) data frames as much as possible. You're splitting up `df`, where you really only need to work with row indices. Also, you're creating a list and repeatedly growing it, which eats memory.

Here's a trimmed down version. I don't know the details on your dataset, but testing it on a data frame of 1 million rows x 2 columns took a couple of seconds.

```
samp <- function(df, size=100, replace=FALSE)
{
    grp <- split(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$id)
    l <- lapply(grp, function(g) {
        if(length(g) < size && !replace)
            g
        else sample(g, size=size, replace=replace)
    })
    df[unlist(l), ]
}

df <- data.frame(x=seq(1e6), id=sample(1000, 1e6, replace=TRUE))
df2 <- samp(df)
dim(df2)
[1] 100000      2
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to account for the case where there are less than "size" rows for an id

Comment: Edited to take that into account.

Comment: thanks! would doing "df2 <- df2[!duplicated(df2),]" with your original function also work? I've heard that using "replace = F" messes with the probabilities, which might matter for the ids that have more than "size" elems

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `replace=FALSE` that I'm aware of. The option has been around for long enough that any problems should have been ironed out by now.

Comment: okay, got it. thanks so much for the help! your function is vastly superior to mine in both speed and memory

Answer (score 0):

If you want to vary the sample size across different strata (columns "uid" in your case, "cyl" in my example), and if you have a dataframe with sizes like this:

```
sizes <- data.frame(cyl=c(4,6,8), size=c(2,333,4))

> sizes
  cyl size
1   4    2
2   6  333
3   8    4
```

Then you can use this call to do your sample, which ignores sample sizes that are greater than the number of rows for each stratum:

```
Reduce(rbind, by(mtcars, mtcars$cyl, function(d)
       d[sample(nrow(d), min(with(sizes, size[cyl==unique(d$cyl)]), nrow(d))),]))
```

Result:

```
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
```